# Population differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So my friend and I got this question for our differential equations class and we cannot figure it out.

Consider a population N (t) that is changing according to the following rules:

the per capita birth rate is a constant, 2

the per capita death rate is an increasing function of the population, 0.25N

the population is harvested at a constant rate, H

(a) Using these rules, write the ODE that describes the rate of change of the population.

(b) For what value of N is the rate of change of the population equal to zero? Your answer will be a function of H.

(c) Sketch the direction field for the ODE when 0 < H < 4.

what we have so far is  we got $dN/dt = 2N - 0.25N^2$

One thing is we do not know when the H gets added in or how to solve the above to integrate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Harvested at a constant rate `H`" means that one should add a constant term `-H` to `N'`, thus, `N'=2N-0.25N^2-H`. Can you continue?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that "harvested" in this context means killed. So I would be tempted to use $\frac{dN}{dt}=2N-0.25N^2-H$. As for how to solve this, the ODE is separable. You should be able to solve it directly by integration.

Comment: +1. But the whole exercise is designed to *avoid* solving the differential equation...

Comment: Part b) should be straightforward. $\frac{dN}{dt}$ represents the rate of change of the populations, so set that to zero and see what happens. Part c) is a bit trickier, but the fact that the ODE has no explicit time dependence should make things easier for you. I suggest looking up examples.

Comment: Ya we got to that part but we do not know how to separate it and integrate.

Comment: @JayBell "we do not know how to separate it and integrate" Once again, you are not supposed to do this.